# smartgit - Executing a command has failed: invalid path ''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime-error, smartgit

I cloned a repo from GitHub but when i try to checkout a branch that i have there, SmartGit gives me the following error:

[image: The error message i get]

Do you know what could it be?

Comment: Image is not clear. Please reupload it

Comment: sorry, i think its clearer now. thank you

Comment: Seems like your repository contains a path with ':' which is not valid on Windows (i.e. it can't be created)